# Images and Icons wont load in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, reverse-proxy, netscaler

I have upgraded jenkins to 2.319.1 and started seeing this issue.
Our Jenkins is accessed via Netscaler endpoint. https://company.internal.com/jenkins.
Earlier I used to access via host:8080 format. i.e http://host:8080/jenkins and everything was working.    It still works fine when accessed like that.

**Image 1 : When accessed via Netscaler**
[image]

**Image 2 : When accessed via ip**
[image]

**What I tried so far.**

1. I have checked the logs. No info in logs. Hence I suspect this may be Netscaler's doing.
2. I tried using Nginx for reverse proxy and it works fine.
3. I tried simple theme to put custom images and icons. It wont work.

Are there any plugins which can provide icons.I have tried dark theme and simple theme plugins, but to no avail.

**Update :**
**I narrowed down the last working version**

LTS : https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.303.3-1.1.noarch.rpm

Regular : https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-2.307-1.1.noarch.rpm

**Update 2**

svgs are present in /var/cache/jenkins/images folder. They wont load in browser.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about [JENKINS-66698](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66698)? There were a number of [PNG/SVG changes](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.319.1). Maybe something missed?

Comment: It is not just folders plugin, but the whole UI and menu.
I narrowed down the last working version

LTS : https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.303.3-1.1.noarch.rpm

Regular : https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-2.307-1.1.noarch.rpm

Comment: Maybe ask the [UX-SIG](https://www.jenkins.io/sigs/ux/), cc:Jan Faracik or raise a Jenkina JIRA (mark regression), including all details plus plugins list. Odd it works directly. LTS 2.303.1 -> 2.303.3 -> 2.319.1, so it's gonna be 2.319.1 (2021-12-01) issue.

Comment: Ahah! Culprit is probably  [Use SVGs over PNGs for the sidebar when possible #5663](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5663). CC:@jan-faracik

Comment: You are right. I was going through change-log and that seems to be the one. So it may not be a bug with jenkins, but with Netscaler.
However I did check /var/cache/jenkins/images and I could find all .svg files there. Do you think some additional config in Netscaler is required to accommodate these changes. I am not sure why Netscaler wont load images with .svg extension. Please check me recent image attachments.

Comment: Is there a way I can switch back to png images via configuration for entire ui.

Comment: I don't believe so, but ask the experts on the UX-SIG. Definitely open aJIRA issue as its supposed to be take the SVG first, fall back PNG, as they work thru to remove all GIF and PNG, so an error/defect or someone jumped the gun. Not familiar w/NetScaler, so no comment. Stick w/2.303.3 and hope for a 2.303.4 for now?

Comment: Sure. For now I have installed 2.303.3. I will be checking with internal Netscaler team as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found the solution. We had a http to https redirection policy in Netscaler. We dont know why that was blocking *.svg images.
The policy is turned off and now jenkins is working great.All the images are loading properly and functionality is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update the plugins.

For me what worked was that I hadn't updated the plugins. As soon as I did that all the icons were available.